# Density estimation with dirichlet process

Tags: r, package, probability-density

I'm interesting in estimating probability density functions in quite high dimension (around 15 or even more). I've heard about Dirichlet processes. Do you know a R package which implements this kind of methods ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the "DPpackage" (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DPpackage/index.html) that provides some Bayesian nonparametric density estimation functions. You can perform the Dirichlet mixture density estimation with 'DPdensity' function.